# Issue with Youtube Gdata API for Android

Tags: android

i m using Youtube gdata api to fetch data from youtube. but i m getting error on line

YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService("myService");

**Here is my Code.**

```
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService("myService");
Log.i("YouTubeApp", "SelectedProgramID: " + urlLink);
VideoFeed videoFeed = null;
try {
    videoFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(urlLink), VideoFeed.class);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ServiceException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**going in IOException block**

**Errors**

```
05-03 19:08:54.085: W/System.err(465): java.io.IOException: Hostname <gdata.youtube.com> was not verified
05-03 19:08:54.085: W/System.err(465):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.getSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:170)
05-03 19:08:54.095: W/System.err(465):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnection$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnection.java:398)
05-03 19:08:54.095: W/System.err(465):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnection.connect(HttpsURLConnection.java:146)
05-03 19:08:54.095: W/System.err(465):  at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:511)
05-03 19:08:54.095: W/System.err(465):  at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
05-03 19:08:54.095: W/System.err(465):  at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
05-03 19:08:54.095: W/System.err(465):  at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
05-03 19:08:54.095: W/System.err(465):  at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:645)
05-03 19:08:54.095: W/System.err(465):  at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
```

**I have added these permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**I have imported**

```
"activation.jar", 
"additionnal.jar", 
"gdata-base-1.0.jar", 
"gdata-client-1.0.jar", 
"gdata-core-1.0.jar", 
"gdata-media-1.0.jar", 
"gdata-youtube-2.0.jar", 
"guava-12.0.jar" and 
"mail.jar"
```

This code is working fine on standalone java commandline project. Whats wrong with my code.? Any ideas..

Thankx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**gDATA** won't work on **ANDROID EMULATOR**.. It alwayz return **null**.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem in my Android app. I had this URL: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos in my app, I replace it to http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos and it work. I think problem in SSL.